# Must reconnect gamepad after every webpack update

Tags: javascript, html, gamepad

I am using the GamePad API in a web app. I am using `webpack-dev-server` to serve the app as write it.

Every time I save, I must physically reconnect the gamepad in order for it to be visible to the game. This slows down development.

How can I prevent this?

---

I am using Firefox 69.0 on Ubuntu 18.04.

Even after moving the thumbsticks and pressing buttons the gamepad is not detected.

Comment: The [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Gamepad_API/Using_the_Gamepad_API) for the GamePad API says the following: "_If a gamepad is already connected when the page loaded, the gamepadconnected event is dispatched to the focused page when the user presses a button or moves an axis._". Have you tried doing just that? Pressing a button or moving one of the sticks?

Comment: @cubrr Yes I have tried that, forgot to mention it!

Comment: Is it visible in `navigator.getGamepads()`?

Comment: @cubrr It is an empty array. If I reconnect it has my gamepad.

Comment: How frustrating! Does the event work if you disable HMR and let the dev server do a full page refresh on save instead? Or with HMR enabled, if you assign the gamepad to some variable in `window`, can you still access that variable after the hot replacement?

Comment: I see the same behavior, looks like a Firefox bug. According to the spec, if a gamepad is already connected then a gamepadconnected event is dispatched once a button is pressed on any gamepad.